# Qt: Linker error with QVERIFY (Qt Unit Tests)

Tags: unit-testing, qt4, qt-creator

Basically I am following the basic example [here](http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtestlib-tutorial1.html). My `.pro` file contains `QT += core network qtestlib`. [Solved] **testlib** instead of typo qtestlib

When I include `QVERIFY`, It get the following linker error:

```
testwaypointlist.obj:-1: error: LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "bool __cdecl
QTest::qVerify(bool,char const *,char const *,char const *,int)"
(?qVerify@QTest@@YA_N_NPBD11H@Z) referenced in function "private: void __thiscall
TestWaypointList::fillWaypoints(void)" (?fillWaypoints@TestWaypointList@@AAEXXZ)
```

**What files do I miss to link?** Without `QVERIFY` the linker error disappears.

Header file:

```
#include <QObject>
#include <QtTest/QtTest>
#include "waypointlist.h"

//
// Testing the waypoint list
//
class TestWaypointList : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT

private:
    WaypointList _waypointList;
public:
    explicit TestWaypointList(QObject *parent = 0);
private slots:
    void fillWaypoints();
};
```

cpp:

```
//
// Fill the waypoint list
//
void TestWaypointList::fillWaypoints()
{
    _waypointList = WaypointList();
    .....

    for (int i=0; i < TESTWPLISTCOUNT; i++) {
        .....
        TestWaypointList::_waypointList.updateOrAppend(id, timeframe);
    }
    QVERIFY(TestWaypointList::_waypointList.count() == 1); // causing the linker error
}
```

Comment: It should be QT += testlib in your .pro file, not QT += qtestlib.

Comment: That's it, I have misread the example: http://doc.qt.nokia.com/4.7-snapshot/qtestlib-tutorial1-tutorial1-pro.html If you write it as answer, I'll gladly accept it. All my fault :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your .pro file, you need to change `QT += qtestlib` to `QT += testlib` (note the absence of a "q").

Of note, you used to be able to do this: `CONFIG += qtestlib`, but according to the comment on [this page](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qttest.html), this is no longer the recommended way of linking to the test library.